# SharePoint 2016 / online sending automatic email based on date

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, email, 2016, out-of-the-box

I have the following situation: I have a list with deliveries, for each delivery there is an expire date, no I need to send a custom email to an internal owner 20 days before exp date, then 10 then 5 and then 1 day ... this i have in SharePoint 2016 but as well in SharePoint online, so has to work basically for both.

My first idea was to create a information policy for a date, and then to create a workflow which would be triggered by the information policy. I would create workflow with SharePoint Designer tool. BUT as we know starting from 2016 SharePoint Designer is kind a getting deprecated and not used, it still works with SharePoint Designer 2013 but still not an option.

What are the other choices for me? But we only speak about out-of-the-box things, no VS development etc, how would I be able to solve this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For sending emails based on expiry date and that to like reminder kind of functionality which should be based on automatic trigger on specific days. Workflow and custom utility is the option. you cannot achieve this with OOTB things.

Though it is true we are not going to have new version of SP designer after 2013 but still it can be used. They are ideally focusing on Microsoft flow, but I don't think a template is available which will cater your requirement.

so you can go ahead and use SP 2013 designer to create workflow...